# Python snippets in aptana

Tags: python, aptana, pydev, code-snippets

I work in aptana studio 3 with pydev. My aptana snippets don't work in python files.
I add ruble project, add bundke.rb and create snippet

```
snippet "ToDo" do |snip| 
snip.trigger = "td"
snip.expansion = "#TODO"
end
```

It works when I type *td* and press tab in some .js files. But it dosent work in python *.py.

How can i make my snippets work?

Answer (score 1):

PyDev is not integrated in the Aptana scripting, so, that's not supposed to work.

Still, PyDev has its own snippets (which it calls templates) and they can be added in preferences > pydev > editor > templates.